# Can't create filter on movieclips in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, mouseover, mouseout

After a long time of struggling with flash...

I have some movieclips and I would like to get a filter only to that movieclip that I MOUSE_OVER.

There must be a different way than type MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT for every single movieclip.

Comment: You need to be more specific.   Are you asking for a way to reduce redundancy?   Show your current code,  and explain where the set of movie clips reside that you want to mouse over (eg are they in an array?  are they all the sole children of a container MovieClip?  Are they all instances of the same library object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this.

**Best:**

*use inheritance.*

If you create a class file that has all the common functionality of a group of items, you can have your MovieClips inherit that functionality.   So you'd create a file in your root directory that looks like this. (let's call it `FilteredMC.as`)

```
package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class FilteredMC extends MovieClip {

        //the function that matches the name of class, is what runs when the object is created
        public function FilteredMC():void {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOut);
        }

        private function mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
            this.filters = [...your filter...]
        }

        private function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
            this.filters = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in FlashPro,  right click your library objects that should have this functionality,  go to "*properties*", and choose "export for actionscript"   then in the "*base class*" text field,  put:  **FilteredMC**.  Put whatever you'd like as the class name (so long as it's unique and doesn't clash with any other class or keyword)

---

**Good:**

If all your items are the sole children of a container, you can loop through all the children of that container and add the code:  (you could also do this with an array of items)

```
var i:int = containerMC.numChildren;
while(i--){
    if(containerMC.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip){
        setupFilter(containerMC.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip);
    }
}

function setupFilter(mc:MovieClip):void {
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOut);
}

function mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //the event's 'currentTarget' property is the item you added the listener to
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).filters = [...your filter...]
}

function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).filters = [];
}
```